# Reductio ad absurdum when there are no premises and just a supposition $S$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I was reading *An Introduction to Formal Logic* by Peter Smith - https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/IFL2_LM.pdf , and on page 36 he explains *Reductio ad absurdum* as:

If $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$ (as background premisses) plus
the temporary supposition $S$ entail a contradiction, then $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$ by
themselves entail $not$-$S$

He "proves" this by showing that $A$s plus $S$ cannot all be true together. Now he asks the question - "What happens when $n = 0$ and there are no background premisses?"

From the statement of RAA, since there are no premisses, $S$ itself must be a contradiction. So we are supposing a contradiction in our proof. So can we now just directly conclude $not$-$S$? In Formal Logic, is this the same as $\vdash\top$? If yes, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Correct, if S entails a contradiction this means that S itself is a contradiction and thus not-S is a tautology.

Comment: Let $A:=\bigwedge_iA_i$. Since $A\land S\to\bot$, $A\to(S\to\bot)$, so $A\to\neg S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as you report, we have

> If $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ (as background premisses) plus the
> temporary supposition $S$ entail a contradiction, then $A_1, A_2,  \ldots, A_n$ by themselves entail $not$-$S$.

Hence, when there are no background premisses $A_i$, given what is said about "entails" on p. 9,

> If the temporary supposition $S$ entails a contradiction, then there is no possible situation in which $not$-$S$ is false, i.e. necessarily $not$-$S$ is true, so $S$ is necessarily false.

A formal correlate of that is if $S \vdash \bot$ then $\vdash \neg S$. But $S$ can be arbitrarily complex, and $\vdash \neg S$ doesn't say the same as the trivial $\vdash \top$. Though, still assuming $S \vdash \bot$, we can derive the non-trivial $\vdash \neg S \equiv \top$.

Comment: Oh wow didn't know you answered on Stackexchange :O . Anyways, shouldn't the last sequent be $\vdash \lnot S \equiv \top$?

Comment: Also can you elaborate as to why $\vdash \neg S$ is not necessarily same as $\vdash \top$?

Comment: Could it be because $\vdash \neg S$ can be invalid in general?

Comment: $\neg S$ will be a different wff from $\top$ -- it is as simple as that!